# I am learning how to code so i have a question?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

it shows the default code only what's wrong with this code? I am a beginner programmer. Thank you!

```
   let age=30;
    switch (age){
        case age > 23:
        console.log("you are allowed to drink beer");
        break;
        case age < 23:
        console.log("you are not allowed to drink or smoke");
        break;
        case age >= 23:
        console.log("you can smoke or drink from next year");
        break;
        default:
        console.log("check your age first in the birth certificate");
    }
```

Comment: default option is when any cases are not satisfied

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `switch`/`case` works. It's a jump table that works for equality only.

Like:

```
switch (age)
{
```

*What is "age"?*

```
   case 23:
```

*If it's equal to 23...*

```
        console.log("you are allowed to drink beer");
        break;
```

*Or*

```
   case 24:
```

*If it's equal to 24...*

```
        console.log("you are still allowed to drink beer");
        break;
```

and so on.

```
}
```

You're providing more complex expressions, all of which boil down to `true`/`false` which is then made into `1`/`0` for the comparison. Your age is (presumably) never either of those two values, so only the default case ever fires.

For ranges like you've got, you should use an `if` statement instead:

```
let age=30;
if (age > 23)
    console.log("you are allowed to drink beer");
else if (age < 23)
    console.log("you are not allowed to drink or smoke");
else
    console.log("you can smoke or drink from next year");
```

Notice how I changed the `age >= 23` case into an `else`, because it can *only* be actually equal to 23 at this point and there are no other options. Therefore, also, there is no need for a "default" case.